# Extend length of max characters in Integer field of Jaspersoft Studio query

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that currently takes in integers in Jaspersoft Studio. I need to enter 13 characters in each of these fields, and then iterate through them. Unfortunately, the field only allows 10 char input at the time. I've attempted to change the field to a string input, but I have so many calls to those entered fields that would need to be cast to integers, that it would seem to me to be far easier if I was able to change the maximum allowable characters in that field to 13.

I'm willing to cast each entered string to and int if I need to, but I'm very new with Jaspersoft, and every attempt I've made so far has failed. Here's what my query looks like:

```
select lpad(num::text, 13, '0') value1
, num::text value1no0s
, lpad((num+ ($P{RangeEnd}-$P{RangeStart})/3)::text, 13, 
'0') value2
, (num+ ($P{RangeEnd}-$P{RangeStart})/3)::text value2no0s
, lpad(( num+ 2*($P{RangeEnd}-$P{RangeStart})/3)::text, 
13, 
'0') value3
, ( num+ 2*($P{RangeEnd}-$P{RangeStart})/3)::text value3no0s

from generate_series($P{RangeStart},($P{RangeEnd}-$P{RangeStart})/3 + $P{RangeStart} +1)  num
```

And here's an example of the typical expression in my report:

```
IF(INTEGER_VALUE($F{value3}) > $P{RangeEnd}, null,IF(INTEGER_VALUE($F{value1}) >= (($P{RangeEnd}-$P{RangeStart})/3+$P{RangeStart}), null, $P{SaleName}))
```

Please let me know if I can provide any more information. Thank you!

Comment: You question is unclear

Comment: I apologize. I'm unsure how to make it any clearer. Is there something specific on which you'd like me to elaborate?

Comment: Try setting field class as Long

Comment: Where is it limiting to 10 chars, JasperStudio preview or Jasper Reports server?

Comment: It's in JasperStudio preview.

Comment: @Sal, That doesn't work, unfortunately. I convert this long to an int, and everything goes fine. The problem is when I attempt to use more than 10 characters, it crashes with a JRXML error.

Comment: If you use Integer, you are constraining yourself to 10 digits. Check the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  Let us know the JRXML error.

Answer (score 0):

This should **not** be done, since your number (13 characters) is above [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) that is `2147483647`, instead you need to define your parameter as [`java.lang.Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)

<sup>The developers of JasperSoft Studio is actually trying to help you by limiting the number below `MAX_VALUE`</sup>

### Example

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_7" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3c26b137-f63b-46c8-8469-de9f24f291f3">
    <parameter name="Parameter1" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="270" height="30" uuid="41fd4d98-bd1e-48c9-ac8c-d8cfae208a5d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Parameter1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: output]